# JS Script Returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, var, nan

I am having trouble with NaN - Not a Number. I have looked at multiple web resources and couple of questions here to try and find a solution but none of them worked. Any Ideas:

```
var cur_lv = 1;
var newscount = document.getElementById("newscount").value;
var btn_up = document.getElementById("btn_up");
var btn_down = document.getElementById("btn_down");

function setButtons() {
    if (cur_lv == 1) {
        btn_up.onmouseover = function() {
            btn_up.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_2.jpg");
        };

        btn_up.onmouseout = function() {
            btn_up.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_2.jpg");
        };

        btn_down.onmouseover = function() {
            btn_down.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_4.jpg");
        };

        btn_down.onmouseout = function() {
            btn_down.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_3.jpg");
        };
    } else if (cur_lv < newsount) {
        btn_up.onmouseover = function() {
            btn_up.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_2.jpg");
        };

        btn_up.onmouseout = function() {
            btn_up.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_1.jpg");
        };

        btn_down.onmouseover = function() {
            btn_down.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_4.jpg");
        };

        btn_down.onmouseout = function() {
            btn_down.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_3.jpg");
        };
    } else if (cur_lv = newscount) {
        btn_up.onmouseover = function() {
            btn_up.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_2.jpg");
        };

        btn_up.onmouseout = function() {
            btn_up.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_1.jpg");
        };

        btn_down.onmouseover = function() {
            btn_down.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_4.jpg");
        };

        btn_down.onmouseout = function() {
            btn_down.setAttribute("src", "/img/arror_state_4.jpg");
        };
    };
};

setButtons();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_up").click(function() {
        var cur_lv = cur_lv - 1;
        setButtons();
        alert(cur_lv);
        alert(newscount);
    });

    $("#btn_down").click(function() {
        var cur_lv = cur_lv + 1;
        setButtons();
        alert(cur_lv);
        alert(newscount);
    });
});
```

As I said, I have looked at many resources and couldn't fix it. I have tried `parseInt()` but that came at no help - no matter where I placed it.

Comment: "I am having trouble" is not a question.  What behavior do you expect (given what input) and what do you actually get?

Comment: This is not yet a question.  You have to tell us EXACTLY which line of code you're having trouble with and describe exactly what the problem is that you want help with.

Comment: Apologies friends - I am having trouble with `cur_lv`, it returns a NaN value instead of a number. I have used `alert(cur_lv)` to check it.

I want it to remove and add `1` to `cur_lv` in order to move a navigation box.

Comment: You have a typo in your first `else if`:  `cur_lv < newsount` should be `cur_lv < newscount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scope problem, this is what is going on:

1. You declare `cur_lv` as `1` [line 2] (because it's not inside a function, `cur_lv` will be a global variable).
2. Inside the `click` function for `#btn_up` and `#btn_down` you are declaring a new variable with local scope (the `var` statement is saying that you are declaring a local variable).
3. When you click `#btn_up` or `#btn_down`, a new variable will be created (`cur_lv`) at local scope, with `undefined` as its value. Next, you're attributing `cur_lv - 1` to `cur_lv`, JavaScript will convert `undefined` to `NaN` in the arithmetic operation, so `NaN - 1` is also `NaN`, and this is the reason why it's returning `Nan`.

The solution is to remove the statement `var` inside the `click` functions for `#btn_up` and `#btn_down`, this way you are referencing the global `cur_lv` (declared at line 2).

[Updated]

You also have some other problems with your code:

1. As @Pevara said, you have a typo in your first else if ([JS Script Returns NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653103/js-script-returns-nan/#comment45603505_28653103)).
2. In your second else if you're attributing `newscount` to `cur_lv`, not comparing them (using `==` or `===`).
3. Depending where you've put your `<script>` tag, your code will not find some elements:
   For example:
   `


       var bt = document.getElementById('button');


   My Awesome Button

   bt`will be undefined, because the script will run before the button exists in page. To resolve this issue, you can add code inside`$(document).ready(function() {`, the code inside this function will only run after the document is ready (it includes this little button).

Try fixing the issues listed and moving your code (from `var cur_lv = 1;` to `setButtons();`) inside `$(document).ready(function() {`. Also, you can use the developer tools from your browser to help you catch some errors.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It has stopped the `alert()` box from showing now and the movement is still not happening.

Comment: @BartWD: I recommend to learn [how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript) so that you can find out why the `alert` doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this code:

```
var cur_lv = cur_lv - 1;
```

It creates a local variable that shadows the global variable. The right side of the assignment also uses the local variable, so the value of the expression is `undefined - 1`. The `undefined` will be converted to a numeric value to be possible to be used in the subtraction, and that numeric value is `NaN`. The result of `NaN - 1` is `NaN`.

The code should be:

```
cur_lv = cur_lv - 1;
```

Comment: removing the `var` has stopped the `alert()` from showing and the required action doesn't happen. I have tested it by entering a static number.